# Is an non-invertable matrix an linear operator?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am under the impression that any matrix can be called a linear operator, even if the matrix does not have an inverse. Is it true? There are many properties a linear operator enjoys; do all matrices possess all of those properties? Is there any condition on a matrix to be a linear operator?

Comment: once bases are chosen, any matrix induces a linear transformation (of course the dimensions need to match).

Comment: I think you need an ordered basis to identify a matrix with a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every $m \times n$ matrix with real entries act as a linear map wen acts over a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by matrix multipication.

Using rows-columns multiplication we have:

$$
A\vec v=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}\cdots a_{1n}\\
\cdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}\cdots a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\cdots\\
v_n
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
\cdots\\
u_m
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
where
$$
u_i=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}v_k
$$
and from this definition you can easely see that:
$$
A(\vec v_1+\vec v_2)=A\vec v_1 + A \vec v_2
$$
and 
$$
A(c \vec v)=c A \vec v
$$
and these are the properties that define a linear map (or linear transformation)  $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $.

Usually we call linear operator a linear map $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $.

Note that here the invertibility has no matter.

Comment: A small mistake: the matrix is $m \times n$, not $n \times m$.

Comment: Typo :) I edit. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a linear transformation is not required to be invertible.  All that is required is that it is a mapping from one vector space $V$ to another $W$ that satisfies 
$$L(\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2) = \alpha_1 L(v_1) + \alpha_2 L(v_2)$$ where $\alpha_i$ are elements of the field over which the V is defined and $v_i$ are elements of $V$.

A matrix is such a mapping with the usual notion of multiplication.
As the commentors state, a linear operator requires $V$ and $W$ to be the same space.

Comment: If $L$ is a linear *operator* then $V=W$, otherwise it's just a linear *transformation*.

Comment: @Bye_World I would call the first one a (vector space) endomorphism

Comment: As far as I know: 'operator' = 'endomorphism'.  At least that's the way I've always used it.

Comment: I always thought operator was just a fancy name for a map in certain contexts.

Comment: Upon looking around the web and through my library it seems that 'operator' sometimes implies $V=W$ (Hoffman/ Kunze) and sometimes doesn't (Halmos) -- it just depends on the author.  Oh well.  One of these days maybe the math elite will get together and sort out all of these ambiguous terms I keep running into -- but until then...

Comment: @GitGud: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28mathematics%29) seems to support that notion. I also never used that distinction. Actually I thought that 'operator' is more common for spaces of functions.

Comment: @cfh That would be my second choice for the word.

Answer (score 1):

The operation of multiplication on the left by an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, written as $L_A$ is a linear operator on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$.

There are several ways to realize this. One way is to choose a basis set for your vector space. The usual choice is $e_1=(1,0,...,0)^T$, ..., $e_n = (0,...,0,1)^T$.

Now if $A$ has a column representation given by $A=(A_1,...,A_n)$, then $Ae_i=A_i$ for each $i=1,2,...,n$, in fact matrix multiplication is defined by this property. Moreover, $$A(\lambda_1 e_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n e_n ) = \lambda_1 A_1 + \cdots \lambda_n A_n$$ by the definition of matirx multiplication.

Thus the operator $L_A$ is linear on the basis elements, and it can be concluded that it is also linear on the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

Once you make a choice of ordered bases {$v_1,v_2,..,v_n$} and {$w_1,w_2,..,w_m$}for two vector spaces $V,W$ respectively, over the same field $K$( though I think the same can be done for modules over the same ring ), then, given a linear map $L : V \rightarrow W$, the map taking $L(v_i)=w =c_{i1}w_1+..+c_{ik}w_k..+c_{im}w_m$ , gives you an isomorphism from the space $L(V,W)$ of linear maps from $L$ into $W$ into $M(K)_{n \times m}$, the space of all $n \times m$ matrices with entries in $K$ , where the i-th column is $(c_{i1}, c_{i2},...c_{im})^{T}$